# Destructuring array inside object inside array in one go

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to destructure the "First shop" value in **one go** from this array?

```
const myArr = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: '28',
    hobbies: ['coding', 'chess', 'cards', 'reading'],
    address: {
      city: 'Some city',
      province: 'Some province',
      country: 'Some country',
    },
    places: {
      coffeeShops: ['First shop', 'Second shop', 'Third shop'],
    },
  },
];
```

Extracting the object from the array first actually works but I want to destructure from the array itself.

This works:

```
const obj = myArr[0];

const {
  places: {
    coffeeShops: [first],
  },
} = obj;

console.log(first);
```

But I can't seem to do it when the object is inside the array. Is that possible in JS?

Comment: You already show _in your snippet_ how to destructure a value (`first`) out of an array positionally, did you try applying that to the root `myArr` too?

Comment: Yes it didn't work

Comment: Are you sure? Seems to work fine in my console. What _specifically_ did you try, and how exactly did it not work? Update the [mre].

Comment: Try this.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUwLwwNoCgYwDe+BMYAhnAKYBcMA5AFIgAWY9ANCQeQOa0MATAA5O3GCxAAjKQEsqEOtnqgAJrLC9ODYCwURtK8ilUGODFFXLrN9ALpdSMa6ssRFRcQWCyoCOvQAyiDUMD5+Yk4EAA4oIABuGsACQSFUMLEJSVSRUaAArmBQKP4MwaEFRSW5BAC+jqTRADbkyR7EUWEgAGbdVFSBktEeygBisijQMBBDhoFUoGCq07Pm9AAqLBPLMyDR9g11DfW4dgDcuLiLU9gdGS1tdHfePX0DQyPdE9AOJCe1dkw8GQaAuV3AEBATSoADomiBeAAKL6TKAASjOQA

Comment: Actually this time it worked. I promise it wasn't working before.
`const [
  {
    places: {
      coffeeShops: [x],
    },
  },
] = myArr;`

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: You say it works, so what makes you think it might _not_ be correct? When you say it didn't work before, what _did_ happen?

Comment: Hahah maybe there's a better way

Comment: "Better" how? It's not clear what _problem_ you're trying to solve.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2):

Putting the object in square brackets works:

```js
const myArr = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: '28',
    hobbies: ['coding', 'chess', 'cards', 'reading'],
    address: {
      city: 'Some city',
      province: 'Some province',
      country: 'Some country',
    },
    places: {
      coffeeShops: ['First shop', 'Second shop', 'Third shop'],
    },
  },
];

const [
  {
    places: {
      coffeeShops: [first],
    },
  }
] = myArr;

console.log(first);
```